# Как получить код завершения работы скрипта PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

Как получить код завершения работы скрипта PowerShell?

Comment: какой-то определенный скрипт?

Comment: Нет, для любого скрипта.

Comment: Может быть это `errorlevel` - код завершения?

Comment: Это допустимо наверно для batch, наверное для ps есть какой-то другой механизм

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это команда\скрипт, который не имеет параметра exxitCode, то можно получить значение переменной `$LastExitCode`

```
PS C:\> ping 8.8.8.8 -c 1
Bad option -c.


Usage: ping [-t] [-a] [-n count] [-l size] [-f] [-i TTL] [-v TOS]
            [-r count] [-s count] [[-j host-list] | [-k host-list]]
            [-w timeout] [-R] [-S srcaddr] [-4] [-6] target_name

Options:
    -t             Ping the specified host until stopped.
                   To see statistics and continue - type Control-Break;
                   To stop - type Control-C.
    -a             Resolve addresses to hostnames.
    -n count       Number of echo requests to send.
    -l size        Send buffer size.
    -f             Set Don't Fragment flag in packet (IPv4-only).
    -i TTL         Time To Live.
    -v TOS         Type Of Service (IPv4-only. This setting has been deprecated
                   and has no effect on the type of service field in the IP Header).
    -r count       Record route for count hops (IPv4-only).
    -s count       Timestamp for count hops (IPv4-only).
    -j host-list   Loose source route along host-list (IPv4-only).
    -k host-list   Strict source route along host-list (IPv4-only).
    -w timeout     Timeout in milliseconds to wait for each reply.
    -R             Use routing header to test reverse route also (IPv6-only).
    -S srcaddr     Source address to use.
    -4             Force using IPv4.
    -6             Force using IPv6.

PS C:> $LastExitCode
1
PS C:\> $s = ping 8.8.8.8
PS C:\> $LastExitCode
0
```

Если имеет параметр, то так `$s.exitCode()`

более подробно можно почитать [тут](https://weblogs.asp.net/soever/returning-an-exit-code-from-a-powershell-script)

**UPD**

```
 function StartProcess{
    Param (
        [String] $path, 
        [String] $arguments = $null,
        [bool] $wait = $true,
    )     
    $exec = "Start-Process `"$path`"  -PassThru "
    $exec = $exec + " -NoNewWindow:`$true "
    #Start-Process -ArgumentList
    if($arguments -ne $null){$exec = $exec + " -ArgumentList '" + $arguments + "'"}
    if($wait -eq $true){$exec = $exec + " -wait"}   
    $p = Invoke-Expression $exec
    return $p
}
```

теперь будешь проверять , что `$myP = StartProcess .....`

```
if( $myP.ExitCode -eq 0){
```

А для скриптов других

```
StartProcess -path "poershell" "myscript.ps1"
```

p.s. Можно вызывать функцию из другого скрипта

Comment: А что на счет "$?", "start process"?

Comment: И не большая поправка, этот exitcode необходимо обработать в этом же скрипте

Comment: уже дан [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/622039/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-powershell-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B8-pid-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB/622057#622057) на такой вопрос. посмотри, пожалуйста

Comment: Каша какая-то, это не ответ на мой вопрос, там по-моему вообще речь о другом.

Comment: забудьте. что именно через "start process" хотите сделать?

Comment: Моя задача следующая: я запускаю из ps разные скрипты и программы(типа архиваторы и прочее), когда скрипт выполнится, переменная $? будет хранить true иначе false, дальше я обрабатываю этот результат своим модулем(так же написанном на PS), и пишу результат в базу MS SQL. Такая схема не всегда прокатывает, потому что переменная $? получает результат в зависимости от того выполнилась команда или нет, а что произошло внутри команды ей все равно.

Comment: используйте `function StartProcess` и обрабатываете exitcode. разве не это вам нужно ?

Comment: я так понимаю, просто для разных случаев разные решения

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53750/discussion-between-senior-pomidor-and-n-turshiev).

Comment: Пишу вам в чате, вас там нет видимо.

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос просто по анологии с cmd но для нормальных скриптов PowerShell, то ответ: такого кода нет и не надо. PowerShell скрипт выдаёт один объект с данными, целиком в переменную или часть объекта на экран и возможно одно или несколько сообщений об ошибках. Успехом можно считать то, что в выводимом объекте имеются любые определённые данные. Это как множество разных кодов завершения, о чём я в cmd только мечтал годами.