# Передать в cmd команду из powershell

Tags: cmd, bat, powershell

Имеется простой(пока) скрипт PS1 :

```
Start-Process cmd;
```

который просто открывает консоль. Вопрос как в открытую консоль передать команду, например `echo 1` ?

Comment: Я бы предложил просто запуска с параметрами `cmd /c echo 123`, `cmd /k echo 123` - как из powershell это сделать, не знаю.

Comment: @Qwertiy дело в том что одним `echo` дело не ограничится )

Comment: есть вариант сбросить все команды в файл, и передать cmd уже сам *.bat/*.cmd файл

Comment: @test123 имеете в виду такой процес - 1ps создает/перезаписывает батник, запускает `cmd`, после чего передает `cmd` путь до батника так ?

Comment: Именно так. Хотя подход не очень хороший. В идеале, нужно поднимать pipe до cmd, и по пайпу писать ему команды и читать ответы, но, делать это в power shell... Не уверен что такое возможно. Да и смысла, из вашего вопроса не вижу.

Comment: @Сергей  [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/622057/209435)  есть уже обертка для запуска команд. вы можете просто вызывать `StartProcess -path cmd -arguments "ping 8.8.8.8" ` и в конце получить результат

Comment: @test123 что бы понять смысл нужно вернутся назад, к сервису `appcenter` от MS. тесты запускаются только из cmd и не потдерживают PS1. со временем запуски тестов стали долгой рутинной процедурой, совмещенной с риском ошибится в выборе локали или тестовой серии. что бы съэкономить время я решил написать простой батник, но работать с ним крайне неудобно в отличии от того же PS. это если кратко )

Comment: @Сергей поясните, пожалуйста, чуть подробнее, чего хотите достичь, что уже получилось. Какой командой запускается тест, почему нельзя просто вызвать из скрипта PowerShell команду через `. someexecutable.exe -args arg` и т.п.

Comment: А если через AttachConsole?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, вот так:

```
 Start-Process "cmd" -ArgumentList "/c echo 1"
```